# component-based power system for a game

Tags: c++, trees, system

My issue is that I've been trying to implement a power/electrical system for a while now. I'm using Unreal Engine 4 with C++ but that's not really relevant.

I'm trying to implement some sort of system of generators, power storage, and power draining objects that all interact through one another through a system of wires or cables, similar to any of the many minecraft mods which add machines.

My thoughts were moving towards using a node system, where nodes looking for power can trace through the system and find a generator or storage cell. I couldn't find a single tutorial or example anywhere online. Anyone have any input?

Thanks!

Comment: C++? I thought Unreal had its own built-in scripting language.

Comment: It does, it's called blueprints. They also give you the option to write code in c++ using the same variable and function names, but with slightly more features. I'm more familiar with C++ so I decided to use that. It also looks better when there's a TON of code.

Comment: OK, now I'm all confuzzled. I thought it was called UnrealScript.  Granted, it's been a while since I did any work in that area, but... has that changed?

Comment: They completely ditched UnrealScript in UE4. C++ allows you to use external libraries where UnrealScript does not. It's also easier to get into if you know the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimenting for a while I have a solution. I've split the network of machines into many **EnergyNet** objects, which represents something like a cluster of wires. Each EnergyNet represents a system of energy suppliers, consumers, and storagers, which are a combination of both.

Every update tick, the energy net measures the amount of energy produces and distributes it to the consumers. Any remaining energy is then stored in the storagers or disposed.

By using multiple EnergyNets, I can create many complex systems with far distanced between them. If two EnergyNets were to intersect, I could easily merge their components the for a single EnergyNet!

edit:
I represent the machines by a

```
List<Machine>
```

and my connections by a

```
List<Tuple<Machine, Machine>>
```

If anyone would like, I can submit my source code, but I have to admit it's a bit of a mess. I planned on rewriting everything once I had figured it out...

Comment: Make sure to self-accept. Some more specifics might be nice for future visitors as well.

Comment: When I press the accept button it says I must wait 1-day first. I'll share some of the source.

Comment: Is this similar to [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29)?